# ARIMA, утечка данных

Tags: временные-ряды

Решаю задачу по временным рядам и, найдя замечательную статью (https://www.kdnuggets.com/2023/08/times-series-analysis-arima-models-python.html), бросился её воспроизводить. Однако, получив подозрительно хорошую метрику начал разбираться, в чём подвох (в статье график предикта тоже подозрительно хорошо совпадает с тестом). И похоже, что код реализован с утечкой данных. По-другому я не могу объяснить результаты. Но где именно происходит утечка, я не смог найти. Предположительно проблема находится на этом участке кода

```
history = [x for x in train_ot]
y = test_ot
predictions = list()

for i in tqdm(range(0, 5)):
    model = ARIMA(history, order=(1,1,0))
    model_fit = model.fit()
    yhat = model_fit.forecast()[0]
    predictions.append(yhat)
    if i < len(y):
        obs = y[i]
        history.append(obs)
    print()
    pass
```

Так же прикладываю свой график. Обучал на 5 значениях (всего 1550) для проверки, изменится ли предкикт. Нет, не изменился

Буду рад помощи, спасибо.

[image]